# Included HTML/CSS Through <object> Is Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: css, html, object

I am trying to make it so that the features that are on every page of the site are in separated HTML files. I made a header.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>header</title>
<link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/inc/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="identityAndLinksHeader">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a>Home</a></td>
      <td><a>About</a></td>
      <td><a>Privacy</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#identityAndLinksHeader
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    padding: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    background-color: rgba(127, 140, 141,1.0);
}
```

The file works fine and looks like this:
http://puu.sh/68SbK.png

Then I have this index.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<object name="header" type="text/html" data="inc/header.html"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I run this, the header looks like this:
http://puu.sh/68S9M.png

Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is you don't  need to define type = "text/css" in html5
and second the width of your #identityAndLinksHeader is 100% and perhaps in index.html, that small area is the 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The object tag's size is only so large.  Try setting its width to the width of the page.